# select с выбором страны

Tags: html

Друзья, каким образом в соцсетях реализуют **select** со списком стран, а 2 - со списком городов, зависящих от выбора страны? Появилась надобность в таких же. Не думаю, что ручками его заполняли. Может, с помощью парсинга?

В инете ничего не нашёл :)

Comment: Всегда поражался вопросам с одними типами меток и принятым ответом никак с ними не связанными )

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, я не знал вообще как это реализовать. Поставил эту метку, т.к. select - элемент html) На основе его ответа я понял как можно заполнить select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле изначально необходимо в ручную подготовить таблицы (либо скачать готовые со списком стран/городов, например [тут](https://htmlweb.ru/geo/geo.php)), первая таблица *countries* со списком стран выглядит в общем виде так:

```
ID Name
1  Russia
2  Poland
3  USA
```

*Cities* со списком городов:

```
ID ParentID Name
1  1        Moscow
2  3        New York
3  1        Rostov
4  1        Krasnodar
```

Далее идет выборка из таблиц

Получаем ID страны

```
SELECT ID
FROM countries
WHERE name = 'Russia' // получим *1*
```

Получаем список городов

```
SELECT Name
FROM cities 
WHERE ParentID = 1 // ИД страны, например, России
```

Comment: Проще было объяснить человеку чтобы он попросту не лез в это, его знаний явно не хватит воспользоваться этим. Подобные списки делаются на js, чтобы при селекте одного элемента, подгружалась вторая, в зависимости от выбранной страны из бд будут браться города которые имеют эту страна.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, можно и без запросов к базе данных обойтись, если очень надо. Вот, грязновато, но работает:

```js
function showCitiesByCountry(country) {
  document.getElementById("style").innerHTML = '#cities :not(.' + country + ') {display:none;}';
}
```

```html
<select id="country" onchange="showCitiesByCountry(this.value)">
  <option selected disabled>--</option>
  <option value="fr">France</option>
  <option value="in">India</option>
  <option value="ru">Russia</option>
</select>

<style id="style">
  #cities :not([disabled]) {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<select id="cities">
  <option selected disabled>--</option>
  <option class="ru">Moscow</option>
  <option class="fr">Paris</option>
  <option class="ru">Sebastopol</option>
  <option class="ru">Kursk</option>
  <option class="in">Delhi</option>
  <option class="fr">Marseille</option>
  <option class="in">Mumbai</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Как связать 2 select'а я знаю, просто не писать же вручную select стран с 200+ `option` и много select'ов с городами

Comment: Нет, конечно =) Все зависит от ситуации. Но можно, один раз сделав выборку в файл, простым поиском-заменой соорудить нужную кучу option'ов =)